# How to get rid of null value table A left outer join pivot table

Tags: sql-server

I want to set those NULL value to zero in result table. I can't find any solution so far.

(A)

```
CREATE TABLE ##Temp1
 (
    tmp_id varchar(8),
    tmp_ac varchar(5),
    tmp_amt decimal(15,2)
 )

Record :
id   ac      amt
1    30100   100.00
2    30400   300.00
3    30500   500.00
```

(B) create dynamic column pivot table:

```
declare @cols as varchar(max)
declare @query as varchar(max)

select @cols = ISNULL(@cols + ',','') + '[' + tmp_ac + ']' from ##Temp1 order by tmp_ac 

set @query = 'select tmp_id, '+ @cols + ' into ##TempPV from 
              (
                  select tmp_id, tmp_ac, isnull(tmp_amt,0) as tmp_amt
                  from ##Temp1
              ) x
              pivot
              (
                 sum(tmp_amt)
                  for tmp_ac in (' + @cols + ')
              ) p'
exec (@query)
```

(C)Left outer join table A to table pivot:

```
select
 ##TempA.f_id  as [ID],
##TempPV.*          
from ##TempA
left outer join  ##TempPV
on  ##TempA.f_id = tmp_id
order by f_id
```

(D) Result:

```
Id   30100    30400    30500
1    100.00   NULL     NULL
2    NULL     300.00   NULL
3    NULL     NULL     500.00
4    NULL     NULL     NULL
5    NULL     NULL     NULL
```

(E) Expecting Result:

```
Id   30100    30400    30500
1    100.00   0.00     0.00
2    0.00     300.00   0.00
3    0.00     0.00     500.00
4    0.00     0.00     0.00
5    0.00     0.00     0.00
```

Comment: because of the Id's we are getting nulls when you are joining them with ID's

Comment: I must include all records from ##TempA. That's why I must show all Id from ##TempA.

Comment: where id 4 and 5 come from ?

Comment: Lets say ##TempA is pre-contained with Id "1","2", "3", "4", "5".

Comment: So you want... select ##TempA.f_id  as [ID], ISNULL(##TempPV.[30100], 0), etc? but the column names are dynamic, e.g. making use of @cols?

Answer (score 1):

You must use coalesce (or isnull) in your main SELECT.
I also added a LEFT JOIN with tempA and you 5 ids.

**Query:**

```
declare @col_null as varchar(max)
declare @cols as varchar(max)
declare @query as varchar(max)

select @col_null = ISNULL(@col_null + ',','') + ' ['+tmp_ac+ '] = coalesce([' + tmp_ac + '], 0)' from #Temp1 order by tmp_ac 
select @cols = ISNULL(@cols + ',','') + ' [' + tmp_ac + ']' from #Temp1 order by tmp_ac 

set @query = 'select id, '+ @col_null + ' /*into #TempPV*/ from 
              (
                  select id, tmp_ac, isnull(tmp_amt,0) as tmp_amt
                  from #tempA ta
                  LEFT JOIN #Temp1 t1 ON ta.id = t1.tmp_id

              ) x
              pivot
              (
                 sum(tmp_amt)
                  for tmp_ac in (' + @cols + ')
              ) p'
```

You must use a second column list because the pivot only needs column names and your SELECT must be like this: `[30400] = coalesce([30400], 0)`

**Output:**

```
id  30100   30400   30500
1   100.00  0.00    0.00
2   0.00    300.00  0.00
3   0.00    0.00    500.00
4   0.00    0.00    0.00
5   0.00    0.00    0.00
```

**Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1
(
    tmp_id varchar(8),
    tmp_ac varchar(5),
    tmp_amt decimal(15,2) 
)

INSERT INTO #Temp1(tmp_id, tmp_ac, tmp_amt) values
    (1, 30100, 100.00)
    , (2, 30400, 300.00)
    , (3, 30500, 500.00)

CREATE TABLE #TempA(id varchar(8));
INSERT INTO #tempA(id) values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Julien! it's work! :) By the way, any additional method to make the Id "4" and "5" to show zero, even they are not found in Pivot Temp file? Because I must show all Id from main table (##TempA).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will work or not but I'm attempting to build query (C) and dynamically add the column names in with an ISNULL() around them...

(C) Left outer join table A to table pivot:

```
declare @cols2 as varchar(max)
select @cols2 = ISNULL(@cols2 + ',','') + 'ISNULL(##TempPV.[' + tmp_ac + '], 0) as [' + tmp_ac + ']' from ##Temp1 order by tmp_ac 

set @query2 = 'select
               ##TempA.f_id  as [ID],
               ' + @cols2 + '          
               from ##TempA
               left outer join  ##TempPV
               on  ##TempA.f_id = tmp_id
               order by f_id'

exec (@query2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Quantumplate! I have finally solved my problem based on your idea. ;)

Comment: Glad it was useful :)  You should highlight what your end solution was to help others, e.g. create a new answer and mark correct if none of the ones provided worked as is.